# Cannot compile a simple JNI program on Debian Wheezhy

Tags: r, debian

I have installed R on a Debian Wheezhy. I want to install rjava package, but I get this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.

Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
If in doubt, re-run "R CMD javareconf" as root.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/babak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava’
```

There is Java on my Linux, If I type `Java -Version` I see:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b24-1.11.5-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is your R 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem while installing xlsx package that has some dependencies
maybe related to java and r java packages...

In order to solve your problem you have to:
- check environment variables $JAVA_HOME and $PATH
- sudo R CMD javareconf

If it doesn't help, try out my configuration with java-7-oracle,

- install java-7-oracle via webupd8 repository [Installing Java 7 (Oracle) in Debian via apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543603/installing-java-7-oracle-in-debian-via-apt-get)

  - set environment variables $JAVA_HOME and $PATH
  - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
  - export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
- sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
- sudo R CMD javareconf

and than retry the installation of rjava

I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 24):

I have solved the problem using this command - shown in error description:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Comment: If you get an error you might need to install the following libraries `sudo apt install default-jdk default-jre` (as explained in this [post](https://shahronak47.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/install-rjava-package-in-r/)