# Issue in the installation of rJava: Cannot compile a simple JNI program

Tags: java, r

I have tried to install the rJava package in R 4.3.1 using install.packages('rJava') and encountered an error. My operating system is Red Hat/Centos 8 and the openjdk version is "16.0.2" 2021-07-20.
The error is the following:

```
>install.packages('rJava')
* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-2.el8.x86_64/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-2.el8.x86_64/jre/../include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-2.el8.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
checking whether -Xrs will be used... yes
checking whether JVM will be loaded dynamically... no
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.


Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
If in doubt, re-run "R CMD javareconf" as root.
```

Unfortunately, I haven't the permission of sudo thus I cannot launch the command R CMD javareconf" as root.
I tried to find the config.log file but I didn't find it, Does anyone know where is this file?

How can I solve the issue?

Thank you,
Best regards

Jessica

I have tried to set the JAVA_HOME

Comment: Your openjdk version according to the log shared is JDK 8: `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-2.el8.x86_64`. I would recommend to avoid using JDK 16 since it was a short lived version that is end of life since 2021. Use a LTS version instead like JDK 8, 11, 17 or 21.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot compile a simple JNI program on Debian Wheezhy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042914/cannot-compile-a-simple-jni-program-on-debian-wheezhy)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to use the OpenJDK 11.0.2 but it doesn't solve the issue. Is there something else that I can do to solve the issue?