# after sun-java6-jdk install: JAVA_HOME not found. /usr/jdk not found

Tags: java

I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229510/266457)

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

and installation went smoothly. Then to set JAVA_HOME I read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3208/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/), but while `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/` directory was installed, no `/usr/jdk` directory was created.

Where is the "jdk-install-dir"? Is there something else to install? and what is the correct `JAVA_HOME` in my case?

The OS is Linux 2.6.24-19-SERVER.

Comment: You need to provide your system information.  What OS version?

Comment: Linux 2.6 is the version of linux kernel you are using... but what is the Linux os you are using for eg.. fedora, ubuntu, suse etc..

Comment: @T.Webster you should go through the official guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java and also this askubuntu post..http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6

Comment: be careful with installing the sun / oracle jdk via the repositories of your linux distribution . you will most likely get an outdated version of java 6 due to license restrictions. Most of the distributions have switched to openjdk since then. If you want to install the oracle jdk you have to use the downloaded installer from the oracle website (or package these installer for your distribution to be able to use the benefits of a package-management. At least in debian there is a helper package named "java-package" for doing this)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for all `OS` and all `JDK version`. OS like `UBUNTU` has default directory set `/usr/lib/jvm`.

And your ***home directory*** is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/`

Comment: By **home directory** do you mean `JAVA_HOME`? mY OS is Linux 2.6.24-19-SERVER

Comment: Which means its `UBUNTU` as I stated in my answer. Yes, it is root home for java. You can set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/` if its not already set.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux 2.6.24-19-server

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/` is the **exact** path to `JAVA_HOME`